# Interpolation over time

Tags: r, time-series, interpolation

In a dataframe, I have wind speed data measured four times a day, at 00:00, 06:00, 12:00 and 18:00 o'clock. To combine these with other data, I need to fill the time in between towards a resolution of 15 minutes. I would like to fill the gaps by simple interpolation.

The following example produces two corresponding sample dataframes. `df1` and `df2` need to be merged. In the resulting merged dataframe, the gap values between the 6-hourly values (where `var == NA`?) need to be filled by a simply mean interpolation. *My problem is how to merge both and do the concrete interpolation between the given values.*

**First dataframe**

*Creation:*

```
# create a corresponding sample data frame
df1 <- data.frame(
  date = seq.POSIXt(
    from = ISOdatetime(2015,10,1,0,0,0, tz = "GMT"),
    to = ISOdatetime(2015,10,14,23,59,0, tz= "GMT"),
    by = "6 hour"
  ),
  windspeed = abs(rnorm(14*4, 10, 4)) # abs() because windspeed shoud be positive
)
```

*Resulting dataframe:*

```
> # show the head of the dataframe
> head(df1)
                 date windspeed
1 2015-10-01 00:00:00 17.928217
2 2015-10-01 06:00:00 11.306025
3 2015-10-01 12:00:00  6.648131
4 2015-10-01 18:00:00 10.320146
5 2015-10-02 00:00:00  2.138559
6 2015-10-02 06:00:00  9.076344
```

**Second dataframe**

*Creation:*

```
# create a 2nd corresponding sample data frame
df2 <- data.frame(
  date = seq.POSIXt(
    from = ISOdatetime(2015,10,1,0,0,0, tz = "GMT"),
    to = ISOdatetime(2015,10,14,23,59,0, tz= "GMT"),
    by = "15 min"
  ),
  var = abs(rnorm(14*24*4, 300, 100))
)
```

*Resulting dataframe:*

```
> # show the head of the 2nd dataframe
> head(df2)
                 date      var
1 2015-10-01 00:00:00 198.2657
2 2015-10-01 00:15:00 472.9041
3 2015-10-01 00:30:00 605.8776
4 2015-10-01 00:45:00 429.0949
5 2015-10-01 01:00:00 400.2390
6 2015-10-01 01:15:00 317.1503
```

Comment: please use `set.seed` to make your examples reproducible. Also please add your expected output

Comment: `help("merge"); library(zoo); help("na.approx")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution

First merge them to get using all = TRUE to get all values

```
df3 <- merge(df1, df2, all = TRUE)
```

Then use approx for Interpolation

```
df3$windspeed <- approx(x = df1$date, y = df1$windspeed, xout = df2$date)$y
```

The only problem there is that the las ones will be NA unless your last value of windspeed is there, but everything in between will be there

Comment: Thank you, `approx` seems to be what I was looking for! What does the `$y` at the end of your second code line stand for?

Comment: You are Welcome @Arne, the `approx` function will give you a list where x are the values you have in full, in your case date, and y are the values you want to interpolate (Windspeed). If you take out the $y it will give you a list which you can't append to your data easily